# How can a .NET background thread detect that the main application is closing?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, process

I am writing a library (a .NET Framework DLL).

This library can be used in various kinds of applications: WinForm applications, WPF applications, ASP.NET applications, Windows services, ... even unmanaged applications (via COM interop).

This library creates a background thread to do some maintenance tasks.

Here's the challenge: When the main application is closed, my background thread needs to detect this and do some cleanup to exit gracefully (close database connections, etc.).

**How can my background thread detect (in a host-application-agnostic way), that its process is about to terminate, so that it can start its cleanup tasks?**

---

Prior research:

- There are multiple ways to detect that the application is closing *for specific UI frameworks* (e.g. [Application.ApplicationExit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit?view=netframework-4.8) for WinForms and [Application.Exit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.exit?view=netframework-4.8) for WPF). Obviously, that's not suitable for a generic library.

Answer (score 3):

You can attach a handler to the `AppDomain.ProcessExit` event of the current application domain.

However, you need to be quick with your clean-up (quote from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.processexit?view=netframework-4.8), emphasis mine):

> In .NET Framework, the total execution time of all ProcessExit event handlers is limited, just as the total execution time of all finalizers is limited at process shutdown. **The default is two seconds**.

---

Often, however, the host application *knows* when it is about to close, so my recommendation would be as follows:

- Add a `Shutdown` method to your library, and document that implementors *should* call it before closing the host application. Do your clean-up there. If implementors do as recommended, you don't have a time limit here.
- In `AppDomain.ProcessExit`, call your `Shutdown` method if it has not been called explicitly before. You do have a time limit here, but it's better than nothing.

This is similar to how the `Dispose` pattern works: `Dispose` is called in the finalizer if, and only if, it has not been explicitly invoked before.